# Write vector with variables and calculate its norm in terms of the variables

Tags: vector, variable

I have a vector `v` defined as follows:

```
v[x_] = {0.5, 0., x}
```

I calculate its norm, and expect for it to be `Sqrt[0.25+x^2]`. But instead I get a number:

```
Norm[v]
1.71202
```

I also tried `Norm[v[x]]`, but that gives `Norm[{1.71202, 0}[x]]`. What should I do so that I get `Sqrt[0.25+x^2]` as the answer?

Comment: Evaluate `Clear[v]` and try again.

Comment: @J.M. That works. Why do I need to do this?

Comment: Because *Mathematica* remembers everything you did until you tell it to forget. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562).